# cannot create ftp session

Tags: networking, ftp, website

Cannot connect to my web sites server using filezilla. I get

```
Error:  Connection closed by server
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Someone suggested I use telnet at the command prompt to my web site, but it returns `Connection to host lost.`
 Disabled antivirus and firewalls. I am connected to my ISP with a VPN connection. Thanks for any help

Comment: Did you check that your password and username are correct? Be aware that they are case sensitive. Also are you using a third-party hosting account or is it your own server?

Comment: Thanks for your help but actually my ISP was blocking FTP!